# Android: Assigning equal height to children at runtime

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to design a layout which has one or many cards inside it. The problem is that the number of cards is known at run time and I need each card to get the exact same height as others. So if I have two cards each one will get a `weight` of 0.5

This layout should push down all other cards when one is clicked.

How to achieve this? Should I develop a custom view?

**UPDATE**

I have tried RecyclerView, I added the following in my Adapter

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CardViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Card card = cards.get(position);
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((AppCompatActivity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        holder.tenantId.setText(card.getTenantName());
        holder.tenantUsername.setText(card.getUsername());
        holder.containerTenant.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        holder.tenantLogo.setImageResource(card.getImgResource());

        holder.itemView.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (displayMetrics.heightPixels / (cards.size() * 1.0f));
    }
```

But it is still pushing the second card down and the user needs to scroll to see the second card.

Comment: did u check recyclerview?

Comment: you really need a RecyclerView

Comment: @RissmonSuresh Yes I have checked recyclerview. I will update my question

Comment: @lelloman check my update

Answer (score 2):

You should put your cards inside a LinearLayout and set the weight programmatically.

```
float cardWeight = 1 / numOfCards;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    cardWeight
);
CARD1.setLayoutParams(param);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    cardWeight
);
CARD2.setLayoutParams(param);

LINEARPARENT.setWeightSum(1f);
LINEARPARENT.addView(CARD1);
LINEARPARENT.addView(CARD2);
```

About the pushdown, you could set the clicked card the weight of 1f (or the linear weightsum) and remove the others and inflate them on another layout.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with @yasin answer, I found part of the solution

MainActivity.java

```
    private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_2);

        mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);

        List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();
        Card c1 = new Card(R.drawable.ic_1, "Username 1", "Tenant 1");
        Card c2 = new Card(R.drawable.ic_2, "Username 2", "Tenant 2");
        Card c3 = new Card(R.drawable.ic_3, "Username 3", "Tenant 3");
        Card c4 = new Card(R.drawable.ic_4, "Username 4", "Tenant 4");
        Card c5 = new Card(R.drawable.ic_5, "Username 5", "Tenant 5");

        cards.add(c1);
        cards.add(c2);
        cards.add(c3);
        cards.add(c4);
        cards.add(c5);

        mLinearLayout.setWeightSum(1f);


        for (Card c : cards) {
            View cardView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tenant_card, null);
            TextView tvTenant = (TextView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.tv_tenant);
            TextView tvUsername = (TextView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.tv_username);
            ImageView imgLogo = (ImageView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.img_logo);
            tvTenant.setText(c.getTenantName());
            tvUsername.setText(c.getUsername());
            imgLogo.setImageResource(c.getImgResource());
            float cardWeight = 1 / (cards.size() * 1.0f);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    0,
                    cardWeight
            );


            cardView.setLayoutParams(param);
            mLinearLayout.addView(cardView);
        }
    }
```